# How can I skip before action for token validations controller in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use before action to require params in every route except auth from Devise.
So, I want to skip the before action on token validation.
I already skip in session controller and registration controller by overriding them but I don't know how to override the token validation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.
Actually, I need to override token validation controller for skip the action which runs before validating token.
Where the action is the method which I create by myself.
For the solution that I got is override [TokenValidationsController](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_token_auth/token_validations_controller.rb) for adding the *skip_before_action* which I already used in session controller and registration controller.

```
class Custom::TokenValidationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::TokenValidationsController
    skip_before_action :action, only: :validate_token
    ...
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't add this as answer, do it instead as a comment, otherwise users don't get feedback.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the first time I question on Stack Overflow. Thank you for your recommendation.

Comment: Don't worry, it'd be useful if you finish this question, for future readers, could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent filters from running before particular actions with the [`skip_before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_before_action) callback, like:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :action
```

Where action is the method where you want to disable `verify_authenticity_token`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually I want to disable my action that is activated every time before going to do others including token validation.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, could you explain?